# How to stop Chrome from prompting for search engine during Selenium Tests

Tags: windows, google-chrome, selenium, automated-tests

When I run selenium tests that use Chrome as the browser, the tests hang. The reason is that, since the browser is running as the SYSTEM user, it continually pops up Chrome's prompt for search engine choice. If I run the selenium server interactively, and as a logged-in user select a search engine, it will enable the tests to run. However, the next time I run the tests I get the prompt.

Is it possible to avoid this behavior?

Comment: As an aside, running a browser as SYSTEM makes me shriek in terror.  I know nothing about Selenium, but there must be a way to run the tests under a normal user account.

Answer (score 0):

This happened with me on Firefox as well. What i did was run Firefox as administrator and answered all the prompts that one time.

Next time when I ran the selenium scripts, those modals did not show.
Not sure if this would directly relate to Chrome, but definitely worth a try.

Let me know if it worked?

Comment: You could use Firefox profile too: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FirefoxDriver

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you 2 options:

a. [Open Chrome with a specific profile](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver#Starting_Chromium_with_Specific_Flags).

b. Write and run setup routine before any tests, which will open [browser settings page](http://chrome://settings/browser) and do whatever you need too:

```
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome


SETTINGS_PAGE_URL = 'chrome://settings/browser'
SEARCH_ENGINE_DROPDOWN_ID = 'defaultSearchEngine'
SEARCH_ENGINE_CHOICE_XPATH = '//option[text()="Google"]'

browser = Chrome()
browser.get(SETTINGS_PAGE_URL)

dropdown = browser.find_element_by_id(SEARCH_ENGINE_DROPDOWN_ID)
option = dropdown.find_element_by_xpath(SEARCH_ENGINE_CHOICE_XPATH)
option.click()

browser.get('http://wherever.you/need/to/go/next/')
```

I'd use option `a`.